# Is it a good idea to use normalised tables with denormalised indexed views?

Tags: sql, database, normalization, denormalization

I'm architecting a new app at the moment, with a high read:write ratio. At my current employer we have lots of denormalised data on our tables for performance reasons. Is it better practice to have totally 3NF tables and then use indexed views to do all the denormalisation? Should I run queries against the tables or views?

An example of some of the things I am interested are aggregates of columns child tables (e.g. having user post count stored somewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's a good idea to have denormalized views if you need to access across multiple normalized tables very frequently.  In most cases it'll be a significant performance increase over using a join and querying directly against the tables, and it's usually not any less maintainable, since either your view or join can be written to be agnostic about changes to parts of the tables that it doesn't use.

Whether **all** your tables should be in the third normal form is another question.  In most applications I've worked with the answer is **most** tables should be normalized this way, but there are exceptions.  Whether to make an exception has to do with how the data is used, and whether you can be very confident about that use not changing in the future.

Having to go back and re-normalize later because you did something the wrong way can be costly, but over-normalizing data that should be straightforward to use and understand can make things more complicated and difficult to maintain than they need to be.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use views to present denormalized data to the user (and you're using SQL Server), you should check out the SCHEMABINDING clause. If a view is schemabound, you can index it, and the index will be updated when the underlying tables are updated. In this way, if the indexes are set up well, people who are looking for data can actually select from the index, so it won't need to rebuild the complex view for every query, but users will still see up-to-date date when the underlying tables change.